# Best of Code Review 2013 — Night and Day category

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for [Best of Code Review 2013 — Night and Day category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1327/9357): The most dramatic improvement.

In your nomination post, be sure to include a link to the answer, as well as a short explanation of how the improvements are exceptional.  One nomination per post, please.  Answers being nominated must date from 2013.

Answer (score 3):

#### [How to make inverse Burrows-Wheeler Transform faster?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/21120/11728)

Simpler, shorter, and 36,000 times faster!

Answer (score 1):

[**Vending machine implementation**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37376/vending-machine-implementation/37379), and [its accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37379/27623).

The original question contained code that:

- Didn't use arrays
- Didn't use loops (instead used `if` statements that all did the same thing)
- Didn't display output properly
- Included an [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error)
- Didn't check the bounds of the entered number
- Wasted memory

The answer corrected all of these problems and went a little further to correct some of the style problems in the original code.

*This question and answer duo reached the top of the [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) shortly after they were both posted.*

Answer (score 1):

**[Retrieving the most recent communication from a user](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1981/9357), and [its accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/29833/9357).**

The original SQL query was an incomprehensible monster, including

- A main query ("A"), containing an inner query ("B") named `AggregatedData` with an attribute name `maxmaxtime`, which in turn used a `UNION` of two queries ("C1" and "C2"), also known as `kk` and `MaximumUserTime` respectively
- Two uses of `SELECT DISTINCT` to deduplicate subquery results
- The query parameter `@UserId` mentioned four times

It languished as tumbleweed for over two years, probably mostly due to its complexity.

The solution clears up the query by introducing terminology that matches the way users normally think of messages: threads and interlocutors.  It goes on to suggest a `VIEW` that could simplify the query, as well as pointing out a dramatic simplification that could be possible using another RDBMS such as PostgreSQL.

By the way, even though the code in the question was a mess, the question was very well composed, including the background, schema, example data, and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

**[Refactoring chart generator in Linq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/38192/23788), and [its accepted answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38196/23788).**

Refactoring a big, smelly pile of nested `switch` blocks turned a monster consoller method into a much more readable 4-liner.

2013 has seen [a number of if/switch posts](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bc%23%5d%20switch%20if%20created%3a2013-01-01..2013-12-31) in [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23), I'm nominating this one specifically because both the question and answer are very focused on the `switch` block, and the OP has appended their 4-liner refactored code to the original question. I think it's representative enough that in future answers where it would be applicable, I might just link to that post instead of re-explaining the `Dictionary` thing.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Optimizing this seemingly slow Query](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/35848/31503)

SQL is often easy to get lost in, and, in this case, it appears that the OP got lost in some perceived issue with ['Outer Joins'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join), and 'overthinking' the problem. The result was a massively complicated query with sub-selects, outer joins, and conditions which, in the end, because of the outer-joins, have no impact on the actual results.

Eliminating the cruft, the results are hugely simpler, and faster.