# Best of Code Review 2013 — Not As Easy As It Looks category

Tags: discussion, questions, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for [Best of Code Review 2013 — Not As Easy As It Looks category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1335/9357): Question that superficially appears simple but turns out to be more difficult than expected.

In your nomination post, be sure to include a link to the question, as well as a short justification (why the question seemed easy, and how it turned out to be difficult).  One nomination per post, please.  Questions being nominated must date from 2013.

Answer (score 4):

**[Optimising Funny Marbles](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/37825/9357)**

Writing a program to keep track of marble counts — how hard could it be?  It turns out that implementing a sufficiently fast program to store cumulative sums requires a data structure called a [binary indexed tree](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) or [Fenwick tree](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.8917&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and the paper describing it was only published in 1994.  The idea is non-obvious, but once it is revealed, it can be implemented in just a few lines of code.

I'll admit, my review suggested a naïve approach that was marginally better than the original code.  Even after seeing a [working solution](http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/3029781), it took me a while to realize that the array, traversed with bit-twiddled indices, was actually a tree structure in disguise, which led me to find the name of the data structure using some Googling.

Answer (score 3):

#### [Is there any more optimal way to solve this idempotent equation?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/25943/11728)

This problem calls for the computation of

> M(*n*), the largest value of *a* < *n* such that *a*<sup>2</sup> mod *n* = *a*.

but to do so efficiently for many values of *n* requires a detour through some number theory, including a rare opportunity to use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) to compute the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Using_Euler.27s_theorem), rather than the usual [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).