# Best of Code Review 2013 — Thousand Words category

Tags: discussion, answers, questions, fun, best-of

Please post your nominations for [Best of Code Review 2013 — Thousand Words category](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1333/9357): Most effective use of images in a question or answer.

In your nomination post, be sure to include a link to the question or answer, as well as a short description of why you think the image is effective.  One nomination per post, please.  Posts being nominated must date from 2013.

Comment: Super-ninja search: `url:*.imgur.com created:2013-01-01..2013-12-31 closed:no`

Comment: @retailcoder Search results seem to be incomplete.

Comment: Yeah.. got a clue?

Comment: In my opinion, ASCII art would also qualify.

Answer (score 5):

### [Parallel Universe Time Wrap!](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/38103/26200)

I was so wrong while writing and testing the code at first place that I didn't even notice possible bugs and corner cases. Even the competition question was so ambiguous, it made me angry **even** why I participated there!

However 200_success's short and sweet answer with perfect explanation along the image make it better to understand.

Answer (score 2):

#### [Best way to work out angle between points?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32558/9357)

I think that this explanation of how to remap axes when calling `atan2()` to redefine the 0° radial and orientation would be pretty hard to follow without the diagrams.

Answer (score 1):

[Drawing a point on a chart](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/30188/23788)

Asked Aug 24 at 20:29 by [user28859](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/28859/user28859).

An animated gif! How could it get any better?!

That said, this question needs an actual review.

Comment: The question has now had the review it deserved :)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Complex logic that I'm certain can be simplified](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/31597/9357)

The question title sucks, but the diagram is effective.  It conveys the inputs to the problem (the squares and the origin, in black), the problem that the code is trying to solve (the pink angles), and the expected answers (the green dots).  It also illustrates the expected behaviour for degenerate cases (the 9 o'clock example).

My only criticism of the diagram is that the colour choices could be problematic for red-green colour-blind users.